# adding a layout once a button is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

In my application I have to create a button(plus). Upon clicking that button, it should append a view like shown below dynamically below another.

[image: view] the view has two edittext in a row. I don't know how to do that one. Please suggest me some tutorial for it. Do I have to make custom view for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout to generate it dynamically, layout needs to contain your email edittext and your spinner.

Then create your main layout as one linearlayout, oriented as vertical, and one your plus button. OnClick of this button, you can inflate generic layout and add it to above linearlayout, so it will automatically push your plus button.

Answer (score 0):

say this is your main layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   </LinearLayout>
```

and this is your layout, to be added (in a separate file)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/hidden_layout"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView  android:id="@+id/text_view"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, this is the inflated text of hidden layout"/>

    <EditText  android:id="@+id/edit_text"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, this is your name"/>
</LineraLayout>
```

in your activity

```
LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
```

now your `button.onclick` code would look like

```
 View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.hidden_layout, main,false);
 main.addView(view);
```

Comment: But how to get values from the edittext since it contains the same id?

Comment: in that case, after inflating your layout, find the edittext from your layout and use editText.setId(int id) to set different id's and refer. also, for your requirement, you might also use a listview.